# Print number in the terminal with a remanent formatted output

Tags: bash, terminal, format

I am working with huge numbers, and I was wondering that: is there a way in order to print numbers with a special format in terminal? For example, print the 3 numbers of the thousand with a yellow highlight, or spaces etc..

I am looking for a permanent change (like the PS1 for instance in the `.bashrc` to get a custom prompt). I suppose that it will be an `export` of something like this.

I tried to looking for an answer but lot's of time, answers are for scripts outputs.

Any kind of help of link about this will be highly appreciated! :)

Comment: check out Mathias's bash_prompt: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_prompt. It does not answer the question that you are asking but gives you code coloring to look at

Comment: It does not, but nice link, thank you. I already colored and personalize things like this, but I do not find about numbers in terminal.
Thanks @pcantalupo!